# How to get Monthly summary data by AMAZON SP-API

Tags: report, payment, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to get payment reports repository data. Amazon provides a PDF for it,
but I want to get the data by API. You can check the images below:

[image]

I am not sure how I can get this data. Maybe, I need some calculations for it.

[image]

I tried this report "GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_GENERAL" and financial API.
By financial API I can get some data but I don't have complete data.
How we can get all the data. Please give me suggestion. Which reports or API can need to be used for it?

Comment: @Brian, If you know about this question. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Sp-API provides
[Settlement Report](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/report-type-values-settlement) to get every payments detail by settlement group. You can check report type `GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2` to see if it meets your needs.